# How do you split a string by new letters in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and I was wondering if there was a reasonably simple way of splitting a string into chunks of the same character
for example:

```
    word = "MMMMXXIIXXM"
```

would return

```
    "MMMM", "XX", "II", "XX", "M"
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the other question closely enough and it has an extra step after what you want. So for completeness, what you want is: `[''.join(g) for _k, g in groupby(word)]`